# How to build Opencv C++ on a DragonBoard

Tags: c++, opencv, dragonboard

I am trying to build opencv library on a single board computer called [DragonBoard](https://www.96boards.org/product/dragonboard410c/) 410C, which has a 1GB Ram, 8GB eMMC, linaro distribution for that board.
When I am trying to build opencv it give me the following message:

`c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus`

What I knew is that I had to make the built with only one process using `-j1` option for the built. Nevertheless, the built never complete and stops on the same file @ 40%.
I noticed that the RAM usage is rising to more than 90% of its capacity. The RAM idle usage 0.41GB/0.89GB.

Therefore, is it beyond the capability of the DragonBoard, or I am doing the build wrong?

Error message:

```
[  1%] Built target libopenjp2
[  5%] Built target carotene_objs
[  6%] Built target tegra_hal
[  6%] Built target opencv_videoio_plugins
[  7%] Built target ittnotify
[ 15%] Built target opencv_core
[ 20%] Built target opencv_imgproc
[ 29%] Built target libwebp
[ 37%] Built target IlmImf
[ 39%] Built target opencv_imgcodecs
[ 40%] Built target opencv_videoio
[ 40%] Built target opencv_highgui
[ 40%] Built target opencv_ts
[ 40%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_operations.cpp.o
c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/build.make:496: modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_operations.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1788: modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:166: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Possible OOM Killer? You can check your dmesg if that is the case.

Comment: Yes, it is. However, why this happens, does opencv require all this memory to built?

Comment: ```[288460.190476] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-161.scope,task=cc1plus,pid=656077,uid=1000
[288460.198687] Out of memory: Killed process 656077 (cc1plus) total-vm:593580kB, anon-rss:538004kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:1188kB oom_score_adj:0
[288460.402654] oom_reaper: reaped process 656077 (cc1plus), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB```

Comment: Yes, this means that OpenCV requres more memory to successfully compile. I was able to find that OpenCV 3.4.0 required at least 1GB of RAM with 2GB of Swap.

Comment: @raliscenda, why it is not stated clearly? I searched for it.

Comment: @AshrafAlmubarak it will depend on lot of variables, would change frequently depending on changes within codebase and so on. Also it is not that usuall to compile such a thing directly on target board (DragonBoard) but rather cross-compiled on developers machine (your computer) where it may not be a issue at all. Other large codebases are requiring even more, e.g. Chrome browser.

Comment: @AshrafAlmubarak Good startimg poit could be [OpenCV cross compilation documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d0/d76/tutorial_arm_crosscompile_with_cmake.html)